# I want to increase the voltage on my electric fence charger

Tags: voltage

My cows keep getting out. I have a solar powered  6volt fence charger.  I have seen one that was hacked and it was very powerful.  I would like to know how to do it.  I could do it with one that plugs into an electrical outlet also.

Answer (score 20):

Don't do it.  What you're wanting to do is dangerous from a safety point of view, but also it would make you much more liable in the case of an accident.  Instead, buy an electric fence that does want you want.  Here's some articles that demonstrate what I'm talking about:

[6-Year Old Girl Killed on Electric Fence](http://jonathanturley.org/2009/01/02/six-year-old-girl-killed-on-electric-fence-of-neighbor-in-texas/)

[2000 Darwin Award Winner Kills Self with DIY electric fence](http://www.darwinawards.com/darwin/darwin2000-30.html)

[Electric Fence Kills 77 Year Old Woman](http://www.nytimes.com/1988/05/16/us/electric-fence-kills-woman.html)

[Electric Fence Laws](http://www.ehow.com/facts_6108738_electric-fence-laws.html)

Now, you might be saying to yourself, "I wouldn't be as stupid as those people".  But do you want to take that risk?  At least if you buy a commercially made one then they have to go through all the safety testing and they assume some or most of the liability in case of a fatality.  Just my opinion.

Answer (score 7):

The AC powered ones are usually better. Also, check that you don't have weeds or tall grass touching the wire as that will reduce the voltage unless you have a current-controlled charger.

But before you do that, is your ground good? If you're in a dry desert-like climate, the ground is pretty poor and the cows are perhaps not being zapped hard enough, if at all. Even around here, when it's summer, the ground often dries out enough to provide a pretty weak charge.

We had a problem with a young colt getting out because he hadn't learned to respect the fence. What I ended up doing was stringing a ground wire a foot below the hot wire, so even on dry ground he would touch both and be hit hard enough to learn to stay away.

Just don't do what I did and absent-mindedly hold the hot wire in one hand while holding the ground in the other -- wakes you up in a hurry :-) That's a pretty good reason for not rolling your own right there: a buggy design could have killed me right there.

Comment: It takes a stupied person to use a 110 vote for a fence I am sure that thia person was talking about how to increase his power with a car condencer or something like that.I belive he wonted a answer not a safety talk.

Comment: That's interesting. You say you held both wires with current passing through your body. What component of the fence specifically prevented that from killing you?

Comment: Probably the low charge, which lets the voltage break down quickly, before the current upsets your heart.

Answer (score 0):

buy a charger that is much larger than you think it should be, well worth the extra money, ground it correctly and keep your fence line form being grounded out, if weeds or grass get on it and its big enough it won't be a problem.  true grounds on the fence itself are the wire in the ground or green trees or shurbs, metal objects that touch the ground and the fence, stray peice of the wire itself on the fence and the ground etc.  when you touch it and get a shock you are the ground.

a do it yourself one is a smart as a box of rocks.  my charger is good for 250 miles of fence, it cost a couple hundred dollars and has worked non stop for 12 years. do the math, do it yourself and save save save, yeah right.

Answer (score 0):

For cows voltage is good. The limit is 10k volts I believe.

The girl in Texas died on a fence that was well under that voltage because volts aren't dangerous if they are pulsed no matter how high usually unless someone has a pacemaker or something. It is the amperage that kills. That man in Texas I believe is being charged with neglience of some type - not for breaking the fence laws he used if I recall very low voltage like just over 100 and 20amperes that is 100x higher then the amperage considered potentially lethal (which is 200 milliamps for 2 seconds or more.) She was hit with similar power as sticking a fork in a socket. Minus inefficiencies, he should have had an exterior fence around it so something like this wouldn't happen.

I have an issue with thieves and so you need to know your local and state laws well. Where I'm at, if you can prove they acted unreasonably - like tresspassing when there are tons of signs warning not to or better yet they jump a fence - that is considered unreasonable and after that point the land owner isn't responsible  forinjuries suffered on their land. Like a fence, like a dog mauling etc.

These things aren't just law, they have precedent of people doing things like hopping a fence and being attacked by 4 pitbulls and barely surviving. They attempted a lawsuit, dirty thieves, but not only was it thrown out they were immediately hit with a criminal prosecution. So know your area laws and similar cases, because there are limits to this liability protection. You can just shoot them if they are unarmed and you can't do craziness like a mine because of different laws about improvised explosive and such. For your cows though you don't want amperes you want volts - unless you want to accidentally kill one when they bump a 10ampere wire.